# application.worksheetfunction.vlookup error 1004?

Tags: vba, excel

i have a debug in my code, but i cannot figure out why it is happening, could you please review the code and see where i messed up? Note the error debug is happening on the ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 line.

```
    'ENRICHMENT CODE FOR VARIOUS TITLES
For Each wbtitle In wbrange
    sThisWorkTitle = wbtitle
    sThisWorkColumnNum = wbtitle.Column
    sThisWorkColumnNam = Split(Cells(, sThisWorkColumnNum).Address, "$")(1)

                'identifying CASH RADICAL COLUMN LETTER
                If sThisWorkTitle = "Account Cash Radical" Then
                scashradicalcolumnnam = Split(Cells(, sThisWorkColumnNum).Address, "$")(1)
                Else
                'do nothing
                End If


                ''' CASH RELATED?
                    If sThisWorkTitle = "Cash Related?" Then
                        wbtitle.Select
                        Range(sThisWorkColumnNam + gspstart).Select
                        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range(scashradicalcolumnnam & ActiveCell.Row), Range(scashradicalcolumnnam & immsstart & ":" & scashradicalcolumnnam & immsfinal), 1, False)
                        ActiveCell.AutoFill Range(ActiveCell.Address, Cells(gspfinal))
                        Columns(sThisWorkTitle).Select
                        Selection.Copy
                        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                     Else
                     'do nothing
                    End If
```

Comment: `.FormulaR1C1` attempts to create a `R1C1` notation formula in the specified cell. As written, the code is attempting to set a R1C1 formula to  the result of a `vlookup` formula (which may in itself be incorrect). If you are trying to set a cell value, use `.Value` in place of `.FormulaR1C1`. In looking at your vlookup, you are returning the same value as your lookup value (via the 1 column argument), so what's the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott has highlighted the problem line.

You could try amending so an actual formula is inserted into the cell.
So instead of the following:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _ 
    Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( & _
        Range(scashradicalcolumnnam & ActiveCell.Row) & _
      , Range(scashradicalcolumnnam & immsstart & ":" & scashradicalcolumnnam & immsfinal), 1, False)
```

Something like:

```
ActiveCell = "=vlookup(" & scashradicalcolumnnam & ActiveCell.Row & _
                 "," & scashradicalcolumnnam & immsstart & ":" & _
                 scashradicalcolumnnam & immsfinal & _
                 ", 1, False)"
```